# Word meaning "of or relating to guns/firearms"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word meaning "of or relating to guns/firearms/shooting weapons"? For example:

> The lack of guns in this TV show reflects the [gunly?] challenged reality of that society.

Comment: You're talking specifically about the discharge of guns? Or is it anything related to guns?

Comment: Anything related to guns. Example: "the lack of guns in this TV show reflects the [gunly?] challenged reality of that society."

Comment: *Weaponry*?....

Comment: "the lack of guns in this TV show reflects the **ballistcally** challenged reality of that society."

Comment: Ballistically works great, thanks!

Comment: @Greybeard You have broken the SE model. Again. Stop answering in comments. All of you.

Comment: No word for this. The expression in common use is "pertaining to firearms". This is what you see in gun laws.

Comment: *Ballistic(ally)* is broader and refers to *projectiles* in general, including a ballistic missile and a slingshot.

Comment: Note that [the single-word-request tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) asks you to provide an example sentence. I've included the one that you offered in a comment.

Comment: As always, tone/register is crucial. It depends if you want something incongruous and humorous, which IMO "ballistically" is in this context, or else you're probably better using "gun" attributively as in "gun control", "gun safety", "gun shop", etc. Your example sentence doesn't seem very clear, so I assume it's deliberately obtuse or silly.

Comment: In the (unclear) context of the example sentence, maybe "overarmed".

Comment: @tchrist It is kind of you to say that was an answer, but as Djintonic points out, it is too broad. It may fit well but then other adverbs also might. It can only be a comment: As an answer, it would only attract more comments.

Answer (score 2):

It's common to use a category noun before "-challenged" when there's no existing adverb. So I think you can say "firearm-challenged" or "firearm-deficient".

Answer (score 0):

*Fiery* is a word given by *[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/69988?redirectedFrom=fiery#eid)* that covers the meaning but *OED* adds that it is historical and rare. *OED*'s definition for this sense and the latest citation from 2009:

> Designating firearms; of or relating to firearms.
>
> <sub>2009    B. H. Rosenwein *Short Hist. Middle Ages* (ed. 3) viii. 317     A standing army was created, trained, billeted, and supplied with weapons, including the new ‘fiery’ artillery, all under royal command.</sub>

However, *fiery* won't fit your example sentence as the blank requires an adverb and it is not really used today with this sense. In my opinion, there isn't a useful single word that fits your blank so I would rephrase the sentence. Possibly to something like:

> The lack of guns in this TV show reflects the challenged reality of that society in firearms.

I've also found the usage of *firearms-wise* and *gun-wise* in some sources but they are not that common also. The suffix *-wise* forms adverbs (and related adjectives) with the sense 'in terms of', 'in the manner of'.

Answer (score 0):

> The lack of guns in this TV show reflects the **bullet-challenged/bullet-less**
> reality of that society.

**Bullet** (n.)

> A round or elongated missile (as of lead) to be fired from a
> **firearm** [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bullet)

***Trigger-unhappy** reality* might be stretching things too far.